# 'Source Not Found' error - attempting to implement simple Activity-Fragment Android application

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to add a fragment to my main activity, this is the main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <fragment android:name="wj.tweetTab.Titles"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The class `wj.tweetTab.Titles` is an extension of the Fragment class which only overrides `onCreateView` to inflate it's xml layour resource:

```
package wj.tweetTab;

import android.app.Fragment;

public class Titles extends Fragment {
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(wj.tweetTab.R.layout.titles, container);
}
}
```

This is the `titles.xml` layout for the titles fragment, it is simply a linear layout with a text view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="TEXTTEXTTEXT!!!">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I try to run the application on my physical android tab I get a `Source not found` error. If I remove the fragment xml from the `main.xml` file the application runs.

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

After looking around a bit - it seems that this 'Source not found' error is show whenever the error comes from the Android binaries.

I managed to see what the exact problem was by looking in the 'variables' window in eclipse and inspecting the exception that was there.

It informed me that the fragment requires an id - that's why an exception was being thrown. Not the most helpful way for an IDE to present you with an exception...nice waste of 2 hours!